CSS background-clip prevents opacity transition only in Chromium browsers
I tried making a very simple fade-in effect (on scroll).
It works as expected in Firefox, but in Chromium browsers it lacks any kind of smoothness.
Here's a stripped down version for debugging. I also made an identical CodePen Pen.


setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('div#interests div.hidden').forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.toggle('show');
  });
}, 1000);
#interests {
  background-image: var(--gr3-flipped) !important;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .8s ease-in;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  color: var(--light-blue);
  display: flex;
}

#fashion,
#lifestyle,
#modelling,
#travelling {
  display: block;
}

.arsenal-sc-regular {
  font-family: "Arsenal SC", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

#lifestyle {
  font-size: var(--lifestyle-fs);
  line-height: .3;
}

#modelling {
  font-size: calc(var(--lifestyle-fs) * .822);
  line-height: 1;
}

#travelling {
  font-size: calc(var(--lifestyle-fs) * .821);
  line-height: .3;
}

#fashion {
  font-size: calc(var(--lifestyle-fs) * 1.1275);
  line-height: .8;
}

:root {
  --light-red: hsl(343, 30%, 52%);
  --light-blue: hsl(195, 18%, 55%);
  --gr3-flipped: linear-gradient(225deg, var(--light-blue) 0%, var(--light-blue) 27%, var(--light-red) 100%);
  --lifestyle-fs: clamp(6rem, 24vw, 12rem);
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex !important;
}
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="arsenal-sc-regular" id="interests">
    <div class="hidden"><span id="lifestyle">lifestyle</span></div>
    <div class="hidden"><span id="modelling">modelling</span></div>
    <div class="hidden"><span id="travelling">travelling</span></div>
    <div class="hidden"><span id="fashion">fashion</span></div>
  </div>
</div>



Please, try to help me out here.
If it's a limitation of Chromium, I'll be glad to hear any alternatives that involve minimal JS.

Can repro, and for what it's worth Safari behaves the same as Chrome. You can get a similar (but not the same) effect by transitioning the background color instead: https://jsfiddle.net/3mu27et1/

@Kaiido this only works for solid on solid backgrounds. I want to use images etc below the text

One way round it is to put the opacity change on the parent element.


setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelector('.d-flex').classList.toggle('show');
}, 1000);
#interests {
  background-image: var(--gr3-flipped);
  background-color: blue;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .8s ease-in;
}

.hidden.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  color: var(--light-blue);
  display: flex;
}

#fashion,
#lifestyle,
#modelling,
#travelling {
  display: block;
}

.arsenal-sc-regular {
  font-family: "Arsenal SC", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

#lifestyle {
  font-size: var(--lifestyle-fs);
  line-height: .3;
}

#modelling {
  font-size: calc(var(--lifestyle-fs) * .822);
  line-height: 1;
}

#travelling {
  font-size: calc(var(--lifestyle-fs) * .821);
  line-height: .3;
}

#fashion {
  font-size: calc(var(--lifestyle-fs) * 1.1275);
  line-height: .8;
}

:root {
  --light-red: hsl(343, 30%, 52%);
  --light-blue: hsl(195, 18%, 55%);
  --gr3-flipped: linear-gradient(225deg, var(--light-blue) 0%, var(--light-blue) 27%, var(--light-red) 100%);
  --lifestyle-fs: clamp(6rem, 24vw, 12rem);
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex !important;
}
<div class="d-flex hidden">
  <div class="arsenal-sc-regular" id="interests">
    <div><span id="lifestyle">lifestyle</span></div>
    <div><span id="modelling">modelling</span></div>
    <div><span id="travelling">travelling</span></div>
    <div><span id="fashion">fashion</span></div>
  </div>
</div>



